# Rails 3 - Associated models with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

User model has a Project model, which has photo attachment using paperclip

I don't recall ever having an issue like this before.  The problem is, the attachment is being saved to the file system, but 
not the database.
e.g. RAILS_ROOT/public/system/photos/id/style/file is being created, but User.find(1).projects[0].photo? returns false

User model:

```
has_many :projects, :dependent => :destroy
```

Project model:

```
attr_accessible :title, :content, :src, :medium, :photo
attr_accessor :photo_file_name
attr_accessor :photo_content_type
attr_accessor :photo_file_size
attr_accessor :photo_updated_at
belongs_to :user
has_attached_file :photo, :styles => {:medium => '800x600>', :thumb => '100x100>'}
```

projects_controller:

```
def create
    @user = current_user
    @project = Project.create! do |p|
        p.user_id = @user.id
        p.medium = params[:project][:medium]
        p.title = params[:project][:title]
        p.content = params[:project][:content]
        p.src = params[:project][:src]
        p.photo = params[:project][:photo]
    end
    if @project.save
        redirect_to projects_path
    else
        render :action => 'new'
    end
end
```

project's show action:

```
- form_for(@project, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f|
  ...
```

I usually would have "resources :projects" in my routes file, but for some reason that was messing up my custom routes (/projects was mapping to the show action instead of index, and form submissions were being processed by the index action) so I removed the resources line. The project-user association is working correctly, but the photo is not being assigned to the project.  I am not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the database storage option to has_attached_file

has_attached_file :photo, :storage => :database

Comment: Paperclip::StorageMethodNotFound (Cannot load storage module 'Database'):

Comment: @abdollar - I don't want to store the file itself in the database, but rather the pointer to the file. Like a standard Paperclip model does, where Model.attachment.url shows the saved file path

Comment: Just serve the url from your file system using apache or whatever. Change the url using a string replace to match your static web server path

Comment: I've never had to do that before. The photo is being saved to my filesystem, the problem is that the association is not being created for some reason.  Using a regex to workaround the problem is less than ideal.

Comment: hmm - maybe this is an issue with rails 3 you haven't had to deal with - have a look at this link http://patshaughnessy.net/2010/5/23/how-to-install-paperclip-in-a-rails-3-app

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, I have resolved the issue, though. I am not sure what was wrong, but I reverted to before i added the project model, and just re-wrote all of it.  May have been a database issue as I ran a rake db:migrate:reset at one point...a little extreme but was getting pissed off at the inexplicable failure